# Let $E, F$ normed spaces and $f\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$. Prove that $\forall a\in E: f'(a)=f$

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have tried to prove it by the definition of differentiability, but I have gotten nowhere. I am not very clear how to proceed. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: It is $f\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$. Sorry about the miswriting.

Comment: Can you cite the definition of differentiation in this context? And where are you stuck?

Comment: What is the best linear approximation to a linear map? Itself

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, since $f$ is linear:

$$
f(a+h) - f(a) = f(h)
$$

hence the rest $R(h) = 0$, what gives the result.

Comment: Why did you unaccepted the answer? Do you need clarifications?